# Jquery on document load function without document.ready

Tags: jquery, function, triggers

I have a characters remaining script that works on keyup, keypress, blur, and change. I need to add to that mix a on load. Here is my code:

```
$('#title_remaining').html(title);

    $('#postshow_showtitle').on('keyup keypress blur change',function() {
        var text_length = $('#postshow_showtitle').val().length;
        var text_remaining = title - text_length;

        $('#title_remaining').html(text_remaining);
    });
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use the `ready` event for this?

Comment: @Guffa I already have a document.ready function above this code but it doesn't update my character count.

Comment: If i'm understanding correctly, do you want to know how to count the characters on load as well as on key up/blur/change etc.?